# Need help to list down duplicate function in a responsibility name

Tags: sql, oracle

I will need to list down duplicate functions within the responsibility name in Oracle

I have tried the below sql query

```
select ffl.user_function_name, ff.function_name, rtl.responsibility_name
  from apps.fnd_form_functions ff,
       apps.fnd_form_functions_tl ffl,
       apps.fnd_responsibility_vl rtl,
       apps.fnd_responsibility r,
       apps.fnd_compiled_menu_functions cmf
 where cmf.function_id = ff.function_id
   and r.menu_id = cmf.menu_id
   and rtl.responsibility_id = r.responsibility_id
   and cmf.grant_flag = 'Y'
   and ff.function_id = ffl.function_id
   and ffl.user_function_name = ffl.user_function_name
   and rtl.responsibility_name like "responsibility name"
   and ffl.language = 'US'
 order by ffl.user_function_name;
```

I expected the sql results will be the only duplicate functions in the responsibility name with value `responsibility name`.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `group by` with `having count(*) > 1` clause

```
select  ffl.user_function_name, ff.function_name, rtl.responsibility_name
  from  apps.fnd_form_functions ff
  join  apps.fnd_form_functions_tl ffl on ffl.function_id = ff.function_id
  join  apps.fnd_compiled_menu_functions cmf on cmf.function_id = ff.function_id
  join  apps.fnd_responsibility r  on r.menu_id = cmf.menu_id
  join  apps.fnd_responsibility_vl rtl on rtl.responsibility_id = r.responsibility_id            
 where  cmf.grant_flag = 'Y'
   and  ffl.user_function_name = ffl.user_function_name
   and  rtl.responsibility_name = 'responsibility name'
   and  ffl.language = 'US'
 group by ffl.user_function_name, ff.function_name, rtl.responsibility_name
 having count(*) > 1
 order by ffl.user_function_name
```

and keep using `ANSI-92` SQL standard.

Comment: Hi Barbaros, can you please help and share a modified query with your suggestions?

Comment: Hi @SonnyMalibiran, how can I help you ? Elaborate please.

Comment: Hi Barbaros, this query is showing the list of all user_function_name within the responsibility. However, can you please help me modify this query and show only duplicate user_function_name values.